# how to use webbrowser to open the link when it is clicked in wxPython frame

Tags: html, webview, wxpython

I am writing a small app using wxPython. I have already save my data into a HTML string. I use the wx.html2.webview to display my HTMl.
And here is my code being simplified:

```
class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
    sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.SetSize((800, 700))
if __name__ == '__main__':

  app = wx.App()
  dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1)
  dialog.browser.SetPage(HTMLstring,"")
  dialog.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

there are images and links in my HTML string. I have successfully display my HTML string. But my question is :I hope the default webbrowser can open the links when I click on it.

So what should I do. Could someone please provide a link to such an example or (better still), post a short snippet here that shows how to do it?

By the way, I used the wx.HTMLwindow before I found it could not display my HTML string in the right way.

Here is my HTMLstring being simplified:

```
    <html>
     <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div#container{background-color:#F0F8FF;width:700px}
        div#content {height:200px;width:400px;float:left;word-break: break-all;}
        div#predict{width:700px;}
        .box {height:200px;width:300px;overflow:hidden;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center center;float:left;}
         img{margin-top: -50px;}
         a:link{ text-decoration:none;}
        </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <br>
      <hr />
      <p>SCCA Predicted:</p>
       <div>
        <a href="http://sideeffects.embl.de/se/C0423006"target="_blank">Eye discharge 1.0,  </a><a href="http://sideeffects.embl.de/se/C0423602"target="_blank">Sensation of foreign body 0.99901248481,    </a>
      </div>
      </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way to do this. You can use webview's `EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING` event. However as the documentation notes, if there are multiple frames on the web page, then this event will get fired multiple times. If you want to go that route and try it out, then I would recommend using Python's [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module to open your default browser.

Here's a quick demo:

```
import webbrowser
import wx 
import wx.html2 

class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog): 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
        self.browser.Bind(wx.html2.EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, self.onNav)
        self.browser.Bind(wx.html2.EVT_WEBVIEW_NEWWINDOW, self.onNewWindow)
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
        self.SetSizer(sizer) 
        self.SetSize((700, 700)) 

    def onNav(self, event):
        print "onNav called"
        url = event.GetURL()
        print url
        webbrowser.open(url)

    def onNewWindow(self, event):
        print "onNewWindow called"
        url = event.GetURL()
        print url
        webbrowser.open(url)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    html = """<html>
         <head>
            <style type="text/css">
            div#container{background-color:#F0F8FF;width:700px}
            div#content {height:200px;width:400px;float:left;word-break: break-all;}
            div#predict{width:700px;}
            .box {height:200px;width:300px;overflow:hidden;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center center;float:left;}
             img{margin-top: -50px;}
             a:link{ text-decoration:none;}
            </style>
         </head>
         <body>
          <br>
          <hr />
          <p>SCCA Predicted:</p>
           <div>
            <a href="http://sideeffects.embl.de/se/C0423006" >Eye discharge 1.0,  </a><a href="http://sideeffects.embl.de/se/C0423602" >Sensation of foreign body 0.99901248481,    </a>
          </div>
          </body></html>
          """
    app = wx.App() 
    dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1) 
    dialog.browser.SetPage(html, '') 
    dialog.Show() 
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hhm, forgot about webbrowser.

Comment: Dear Mike, thank you for your help. But when I print the url, it is empty. So the step"url = event.GetURL()" doesn't get anything. I have posted my HTMLstring upside. Hope you can help me more.

Comment: The event I used isn't called when clicking on the links. Of course, webview itself isn't working with them either, which is weird. It should load the links too. It seems to ignore links if the target is set to blank though (at least on Windows 7), which seems like a bug to me. Remove the target part from the html string and it will work.

Comment: I take that back...you just have to use the EVT_WEBVIEW_NEWWINDOW to catch the blank target. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: does anyone have a solution for using `wx.html` instead of `wx.html2`?

Answer (score 0):

I use the desktop module for that, edited using Mike's example but using desktop module instead of webbrowser.

```
import wx 
import wx.html2

import desktop

html = """
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
   div#container{background-color:#F0F8FF;width:700px}
   div#content {height:200px;width:400px;float:left;word-break: break-all;}
   div#predict{width:700px;}
   .box {height:200px;width:300px;overflow:hidden;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position:center center;float:left;}
    img{margin-top: -50px;}
    a:link{ text-decoration:none;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
 <br>
 <hr />
 <p>SCCA Predicted:</p>
  <div>
   <a href="http://sideeffects.embl.de/se/C0423006" >Eye discharge 1.0,  </a><a href="http://sideeffects.embl.de/se/C0423602" >Sensation of foreign body 0.99901248481,    </a>
 </div>
 </body></html>
"""

class MyBrowser(wx.Dialog): 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
        self.browser.Bind(wx.html2.EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, self.onNav)
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
        self.SetSizer(sizer) 
        self.SetSize((700, 700)) 

    def onNav(self, event):
        print "onNav called"
        url = event.GetURL()
        print url
        self.openExternal(url)

    def openExternal(self, url, doclear=False):
        """
        Open an external file with desktop module.

        :param `url`: the file url to open in external program
        :param `doclear`: clear InfoBar message

        """
        wx.BeginBusyCursor()
        try:
            desktop.open(url.strip())
        except OSError:
            text = (_(u'Your default browser could not be opened, \
    or the external program was not found or no \
    external program is defined for this file.'))
        wx.EndBusyCursor()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = wx.App()
    with MyBrowser(None, -1) as dlg:
        dlg.browser.SetPage(html, '') 
        dlg.ShowModal() 
    app.MainLoop()
```

I also use 'with' to create the dialog, this ensures that it is getting destroyed when one with done with it.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/desktop

If you need it on Py3 I made some changes which you can get here:
https://bitbucket.org/wbruhin/desktop

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner. I don't quite understand your answer. How can I get the URL I clicked?

Comment: Mike gave you a nicer answer.  Now if you would like to use desktop module then you would call the openExternal method in the onNav handler instead of webbrowser.  The desktop module has the advantage that it opens not only a web browser but could only open e.g. Acrobat reader if the url is pointing to a .pdf.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the desktop module, except that it's a separate package. Other than that, it looks cool.

Comment: Dear Werner, I have tried the desktop, But it also can not get the hyper link I click.